# Dynamic images don't load

Tags: javascript, react-native

App downloads images at every start in `'./res/'` folder near index.android.js using [RNFS](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs)L|:

```
var LOGOPATH = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath+'/res/';
RNFS.downloadFile({
            fromUrl: HOST+'logos/'+i.logo,
            toFile : LOGOPATH+i.logo
          }).catch(function(e){console.log(e)})
```

And then I try to load this image with following code:

```
  <View style={styles.ConferenceVerticalItemImageWrap}>
      <Image style={[styles.ConferenceVerticalItemImage,{height: height*264/1920, width: height*264/1920}]} resizeMode='contain' source={{uri:LOGOPATH+this.props.logo}}/>
    </View>
```

Images downloads correctly and folder contains images but they don't appear on the screen.

Comment: Can you post any more code or give us a few more details of what's happening? It's very difficult to diagnose and issue like this with these sparse details

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute URL instead.

e.g.

`RNFS.MainBundlePath + "/res/" + image`

to be adapted with your folders. and maybe you should use one of the other constant from here: https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs#constants

> BTW, I don't know how you get the local image downloaded, but you should probably try to make your downloading library giving you the full path in the first place.

Comment: I've added more info

Comment: And I've tried your proposition and have made my own constant with RNFS constant inside, but it doesn't works.